# How to put Carousel in center

Tags: html, carousel

[Screenshot of Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXQW2.jpg)

Hi guys, im working with HTML and right now i just added a carousel item to my html project, my question is how can you display the carousel in the middle of the page since it appears at the left side.

EDIT: heres carrousel code

```
<div class="box-body">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
              <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>

            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3420161/Android_800_thumb800.jpg" alt="First slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>ANDROID</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.channelbiz.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ios-7-1-hs-increasecontrast.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>IOS</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://www.baquia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/pc-con-windows-7.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                  <h4>WINDOWS</h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
              <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Comment: you can put your carousel in a div and do some css on it to align it to center OR you can use `<Center>` tag

Comment: @Lakshya the `<center>` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

Comment: Yeah Right he asked for both HTML and HTML5 So that is for particular HTML

Comment: @Maihan added carousels code.

Comment: @JoséCarlosLoarcaHass I answered your question. Try it and let me know. Do you have online link to preview?

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware that this is just a guess, but plausible solutions include:

- **If it's a `position:relative;` element:** set the element that contains your carousel to `display:block;` and give it `margin:0 auto;`. This will make its top and bottom margins 0 and its left and right margins automatic, so you can think of it as the lateral margins fighting each other so your element ends up in the middle.
- **If it's a `position:absolute;` element:** give it the following CSS:

---

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

*I will update the answer when you provide more code if needed.*

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply add a margin-left: X%;(Change X to how ever much ou want) to your css and put it in the middle of the page.

Comment: This will not center the element, or at the very least not responsively.

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that its a div tag, so heres a jsfiddle that center aligns a div tag

```
<div class="center-div"></div>

body
{
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}
.center-div
{
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/McDTommy/ctev6aLv/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.box-body {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried that but it only makes carousel bigger, i dont have online preview since im working with a localhost.

Comment: @JoséCarlosLoarcaHass specify the width for `.box-body`.